# Why does mapping to a List inside lifted query fail with "Slick does not know how to map the given types."?

Tags: slick-2.0

I am trying to map to a `List` inside a Slick lifted query, and I get a compilation error:

```
No matching Shape found.
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
[error]   Required level: scala.slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: Seq[String]
[error]    Unpacked type: T
[error]      Packed type: G
```

Why is it that in a non-Slick map operation, I can map to any type, whereas in a Slick query, I can map to simple Scala types, but not to a Scala `List`?

Comment: Slick has a type-level mechanism to restrict to currently supported types. What's your query?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that limit what query results you can accomplish with Slick compared to naked SQL? does "currently supported types" mean that allowing `List` was just not implemented yet?

Comment: Matt, please show me what query produces that error message and I'll tell you how to write it so it works or if it is not supported. Probably you need to use inSet instead of in as an operator. Regarding SQL, Slick sometimes can do some more things, some less things. Depends on the dialect as well. There are cases where you have to fallback to plain SQL.

Comment: Will sterilize/organize my code for posting here, if your comment doesn't already solve it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
import slick.driver.(yourDB)Driver.api._
```